# Order for revealing hands with multiple side pots in play

Tags: texas-hold-em, side-pots

The scenario (6 players):

Flop:

> Player A is all-in ($50)
>   Player B is all-in ($50)
>   4 others call.

Turn:

> Player C is all-in ($100)
>   Player D is all-in ($100)

River:

> Player E (the button) raises $100
>   Player F calls $100

I'm revealing from the higher side pot (the river pot), to the lower side pot, to the main pot. I know to check Player E's hand first since he raised on the river, then Player F's hand, but who's first to reveal in the next side pot (Player C or Player D)? Should I start with the player nearest to the dealer's left?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Player E shows the hand first, and then players reveal their cards in clockwise manner. The dealer selects winner(s) of sidepots and main pots.

"Players are encouraged to show their cards promptly to avoid delaying the game, but if there is any reluctance, they are required to show them in clockwise order, beginning with the last player who bet or raised in the last betting round, or with the player who began the last betting round if everyone checked." ([source](http://www.pagat.com/poker/rules/betting.html#showdown))

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have a question to your answer. Wouldn't PlayerD's All-in be considered a Call since he's calling and going all-in at the same time, in response to PlayerC's All-in?

Comment: I'm sorry on a second thought, I made a mistake. The showdown is encouraged to be as quick as possible. The last player to bet opens his/her cards, and the rest follow in a clockwise order.

Comment: Good source link.